# SAS / Excel - Expand Single Cell Containing Alt+Enter into Rows

Tags: excel, import, sas, import-from-excel

*( Beginner in SAS, some SQL, and some Excel experience (No VBA) )*

I have a scenario where I wish to break-up a data dictionary in Excel into SAS data. The data dictionary contains Alt+Enters (line breaks) within a cell that I want to break up into separate rows.

My tools:

- SAS 9.4 on Windows 7
- Excel 2010

Actual Excel data (with Alt+Enter):

```
Variable     | Cell
Name         | Value
-------------------------
Var1         | Val1 = abc     <- there is an Alt+Enter
             | Val2 = def     <- there is an Alt+Enter
             | Val3 = ghi
-------------------------
Var2         | Val1 = jkl     <- there is an Alt+Enter
             | Val2 = mno
-------------------------
Var3         |
-------------------------
Var4         | Words
```

I want my final data (in SAS) to look like:

```
Variable     | Var      | Var
Name         | Code     | Value
-------------------------------
Var1         | Val1     | abc
Var1         | Val2     | def
Var1         | Val3     | ghi
-------------------------------
Var2         | Val1     | jkl
Var2         | Val2     | mno
-------------------------------
Var3         |          |
-------------------------------
Var4         | Words    |
```

In this case, I see that I need to:

1. Use the Excel line breaks (Alt + Enter) within a cell as a
   delimiter (row?)
2. Use the equal sign (=) as a delimiter
3. Maintain the variable name when I expand out the data values

Notes:

- There can be blank values in the original cell values
- There can be values without equal signs (=) in the original cell values

**Looking for recommendations on the best way to perform this (e.g., just import the Excel file to SAS, and work with it in the SAS tool).**

This is my current data import step to bring the Excel spreadsheet into SAS:

```
PROC IMPORT datafile="filepath" dbms=xlsx out=temp REPLACE;
RANGE="SheetName$A1:B";
DATAROW=2;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel will place a carriage return where the Alt-Enter is pressed.

```
data want ;
  set temp;
  do i=1 to countw(cellvalue,'0d'x);
    varcode = scan(cellvalue,i,'0d'x);
    varvalue = scan(varcode,2,'=');
    varcode = scan(varcode,1,'=');
    output;
  end;
run;
```